# Siunitx and cancel package

Tags: siunitx, cancel

I want to symbolically cancel out units using the siunitx package. To do so I tried the cancel package as in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per=frac]{siunitx}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\SI{7}{\m}}{\SI{3}{\m}} =  \frac{\SI{7}{\cancel \m}}{\SI{3}{\cancel \m}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But this gives me the following output, i.e. when using `\cancel` the font of the unit changes which is not desired. Any idea how to fix this?

[image: output]

**Edit**: I tried @percusse's solution which works very well. But if I also add the option `expproduct=cdot` to the package options, the problem reappears.

Comment: On your edit, you are using v1 option names which forces compatibility mode. Version 1 did not 'know' `\cancel`, so unsurprisingly it treats things a bit oddly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Switching to `exponent-product=\cdot` worked.

Comment: Finally the problem was that the documentation of siunitx on my box was not up to date. So I didn't find the option `exponent-product` as well as `per-mode`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using an old type of option to [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx). If I fix the option everything is shown as expected. It also warns you to use the version 2 type inputs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\SI{7}{\m}}{\SI{3}{\m}} =  \frac{\SI{7}{\cancel\m}}{\SI{3}{\cancel\m}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I add the option: `expproduct=cdot` to the package option list, the problem reappears. Any idea?

Comment: @student Have a look at the list on page 75, you'll see the newer version for that option. (I have the version released on 2012/7/22)