# Packages siunitx and cancel not working together

Tags: siunitx, cancel

So I tried to use the MWE in the answer to [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78424/siunitx-and-cancel-package)

However my output looks identical to the original post's problem.

I checked using `\listfiles` and my version of `siunitx` has cancel support.
How do I get `cancel` and `siunitx` to work together?

I'm using TeXLive 2014 from the Arch repositories.

```
*File List*
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
siunitx.sty    2015/01/21 v2.6e A comprehensive (SI) units package
expl3.sty    2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (loader)
expl3-code.tex    2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer
etex.sty    2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
l3unicode-data.def    2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Unicode data
l3pdfmode.def    2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
xparse.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3keys2e.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
translator-language-mappings.tex
cancel.sty    2013/04/12 v2.2 Cancel math terms
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2015/01/21 v2.6e siunitx: Abbreviated units
```

Comment: Please edit in your `\listflles` output: 'has support' doesn't really help us. (Things certainly work with an up-to-date `siunitx`.)

Comment: I added the `\listfiles`.

Comment: You'll need to update `siunitx`: there was a bug with support for `\cancel` in the version you've got installed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software and has been solved with an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/264), there was a bug in `siunitx` that was fixed about a month ago.

To fix this problem while I wait for TeXLive 2015, I downloaded the zip file from the releases section the that page, and then unzipped it, ran `tex siunitx.dtx`, and copied the `siunitx.sty` and the `siunitx*.cfg` files into the root of my project.

Comment: Wait for texlive 2015? It has been out since June.

Comment: It's still in the Arch Linux Testing Repositories. It'll probably reach stable sometime in the next 2 months.

Comment: This is why I do not rely on getting latex through a Linux distribution. Too far behind.